# Deploy a lightning page from sandbox to production

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We are working on sandbox org which has an installed managed package.

This managed package has a custom object. I had to add a button on the Lightning record detail page of the object. As this was the managed package object I was not having the edit access to the lightning page, hence I cloned the existing one and while editing the cloned one I dropped a custom lightning component from the App Builder.

When deploying the changes from Sandbox to Production. I created an outbound changeset and added the new page from the Lightning Page section. 
This changeset on deploying to production fails with the message.
"Invalid Component [Related_List_View]: missing required property[SObjecttype]"

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a known issue from Salesforce.
Check this https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCJgQAM&title=invalid-component-force-relatedlistsinglecontainer-error-when-deploying-a-change-set-containing-a-case-lightning-page-with-an-email-related-list
If your issue is related to this known issue, then you have to wait or do any other workaround.
If your issue is not related to this, check the component and deploy along with its dependency.